# How to terminate request flow at spring cloud api gateway and redirecting to different URL route Path

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I have implemented the following microservice applications.

*Request flow.*

> Ui Client(http://localhost:8080) ------> spring cloud
> gateway(http://localhost:8081) ------> user
> microservice(http://localhost:8602)(api
> endpoint=/api/v1/users/bulkUpload)

I am sending an Ajax request to user microservice through the spring cloud gateway service.
Ajax request contains refresh token as a cookie value.

```
     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/users/bulkUpload",
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                data: newData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                crossDomain: false,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 600000,
                success: function (data) {
......
}
```

but if the refresh token is not available in Ajax request I want to terminate the request at API gateway level and i want to redirect the user to the Ui client logout page(http://localhost:8080/Logout).
for that, I have implemented a spring cloud gateway filter as follows.

```
@Component
public class AccessTokenCheckingGlobalFilterPre extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AccessTokenCheckingGlobalFilterPre.Config> {

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-id}")
    private String client_id;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-secret}")
    private String client_secret;

    
    
    public AccessTokenCheckingGlobalFilterPre() {
        super(AccessTokenCheckingGlobalFilterPre.Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(AccessTokenCheckingGlobalFilterPre.Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
             Route route = exchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_ROUTE_ATTR);
             ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
             ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
             
             if(route!=null && request.getPath().toString().contains("oauth/token")) {
                 
                 return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).response(response).build());

             }else {
                
                 MultiValueMap<String, HttpCookie> cookies = request.getCookies();
                 List<HttpCookie> accessTokenList =  cookies.get("access_token");
                 List<HttpCookie> refreshTokenList =  cookies.get("refresh_token");
                 HttpHeaders heraders = request.getHeaders();
                 String access_token="";
                 String refresh_token = "";
                 if(accessTokenList != null) {
                   access_token = accessTokenList.get(0).getValue();
                 }
                 
                 if(refreshTokenList != null) {
                   refresh_token = refreshTokenList.get(0).getValue();
                 }

                 
                 if(access_token.isEmpty() && !refresh_token.isEmpty()) {
                     
                     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                     String credentials = client_id + ":" + client_secret;
                     String encodedCredentials = new String(Base64.encode(credentials.getBytes()));

                    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);

                    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

                    String access_token_url = "http://localhost:8602/oauth/token";
                    access_token_url += "?grant_type=refresh_token";
                    access_token_url += "&refresh_token=" + refresh_token;

                    ResponseEntity<String> aouthResponse = restTemplate.exchange(access_token_url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
                    String responseJson = access_token = aouthResponse.getBody();
                    
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    JsonNode node = null;
                    try {
                        node = mapper.readTree(responseJson);
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                    String newRefreshToken = node.path("refresh_token").asText();
                    String newAccessToken = node.path("access_token").asText();
                    int expiresIn = Integer.parseInt(node.path("expires_in").asText());
                    int refreshTokenExpireTime = Integer.parseInt(node.path("refreshTokenExpires_In").asText());

                    
                    ResponseCookie accessTokenCookie = ResponseCookie.from("access_token", newAccessToken)
                            .path("/")
                            .maxAge(expiresIn)
                            .build();
                    
                    ResponseCookie refreshTokenCookie = ResponseCookie.from("refresh_token", newRefreshToken)
                            .path("/")
                            .maxAge(refreshTokenExpireTime)
                            .build();
                    
                    response.addCookie(refreshTokenCookie);
                    response.addCookie(accessTokenCookie);
                    
                    access_token = newAccessToken;
                            
                 
                 }else if(refresh_token.isEmpty()){
                     //request.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/Logout"));
                     response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT);
                     response.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/Logout"));
                     //response.setComplete();
                     return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).response(response).build());

                 }
                 
                 final String value = access_token;
                 
                 request = request.mutate()
                         .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.add("Authorization", "Bearer  " + value))
                         .build();
                
                 
             }
             
             return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).response(response).build());

            
            
        };
    }
    

    public static class Config {

    }
}
```

this logic has been implemented to check whether refresh token present in the request.
unless it is redirecting Ui client logout page(http://localhost:8080/Logout).

```
}else if(refresh_token.isEmpty()){
                     //request.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/Logout"));
                     response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT);
                     response.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/Logout"));
                     //response.setComplete();
                     return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).response(response).build());

                 }
```

but still, no request termination happening at the API gateway level and the request still is forwarding to user microservice.

**How to terminate the request flow at apigateway filter and redirect back to ui client logout page.**

Comment: maybe the gateway response HTTP error (so that the request flow terminated).And redirection should occur in the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
}else if(refresh_token.isEmpty()){
                     //request.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/Logout"));
                     response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT);
                     response.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/Logout"));
                     //response.setComplete();
                     return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).response(response).build());

             }
```

to redirect the user, use

```
}else if(refresh_token.isEmpty()){
    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FOUND); //302
    response
            .getHeaders()
            .set("Location", "/logout");

    return response.setComplete();

                 }
```